# Редактирование значения типа float в TextInput

Tags: react-native

Пишу приложение с использованием React Native, redux и SQLite. Есть некоторая форма, которую пользователь должен заполнить. Одно из полей - числовое с дробной частью (сумма с копейками). В базе данных данное поле хранится в типе данных float. Однако элемент TextInput в качестве свойства value может принимать только строку.

Я не могу понять, как правильно работать с таким полем при условии, что данные загружаются из базы данных в формате float и становятся доступны через свойства redux в элементе. На каком этапе их нужно преобразовывать к числу и обратно?

Answer (score 0):

Однозначного ответа тут нет, можно по-разному подходить к этой проблеме.

#### Вариант 1: специальный компонент для редактирования чисел

Можно сделать компонент, который оборачивает стандартный TextInput, и реализует редактирование именно чисел нужного формата. Вот очень упрощённый пример реализации такого компонента:

```
 function FloatInput(props) {
   return (
       <TextInput
           {...props}
           value={String(props.value)}
           onChange={({ nativeEvent: { text} }) => props.onChage(Number(text))}
       />
   );
}
```

#### Вариант 2: конвертировать данные перед помещением их в store

Можно при получении данных от сервера конвертировать значение из числа в строку (и наоборот — при отправке данных на сервер делать обратную конвертацию из строки в число).

Где именно производить такую конвертацию, зависит от того, используется ли какое-то middleware для redux (thunk или redux-saga). Общий ответ — там, где получается ответ от сервера и полученный результат помещается в store.

#### На мой взгляд, первый вариант более предпочтительный

- В store будут находиться семантически корректные данные (работаем-то мы с числом, а не строкой — так с чего бы хранить в store строку?). Если, например, в редьюсере потребуется делать какие-то вычисления с этим числом, это будет не очень удобно делать со строковым представлением числа.
- Отдельный компонент реализует логику редактирования числа, это упрощает понимание системы и упростит в будущем реализацию функционала, специфичного именно для редактирования чисел (напрмер, валидацию или кнопки больше/меньше).

Пожалуй, можно придумать и какие-то другие варианты. Например, можно поискать готовый компонент для редактирования чисел (но с ним придётся отдельной разбираться).